# Ruby rails - submit_tag / button_tag switch/toggle between names

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I switch/toggle names between two or more names on single button?
For one condition I want the name to be as "Add", and for the other condition I want the name changed to "Remove". and switch between them based on status at the back end.

```
  <%= button_tag "Add" , :id => "add_or_remove_button", :onclick => "javascript:add_or_remove_button()"%>
```

I can do "Add/Remove", and clicking on the same button will still do the job. But I want it specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't say where the condition comes from, I will assume it is in an instance variable called `@button_condition`

You can do this (I haven't tested it)

```
button_tag(:type => 'button',:onclick => "javascript:add_or_remove_button()", :id => "add_or_remove_button") do
  if @button_condition == X
   "Add"
  else
   "Remove"
  end
end
```

Take a look at: [Button tag documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-button_tag)

Comment: Cool! Yes that exactly what I have, change the name based on the status came from the instance veritable. thanks for the quick answer!